# PayPal querystring seems corrupt

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, sandbox

I'm trying to implement [this very simple PayPal payment integration](http://www.evoluted.net/thinktank/web-development/paypal-php-integration) into my site's cart. The issue I'm having is that when the page should be pinging PP and checking the data, it instead sends the visitor to the PP developer home page.  Here's the part where it builds the querystring:

```
// Check if paypal request or response
if(!ISSET($_POST["txn_id"]) && !isset($_POST["txn_type"])){
    $querystring = '';

    // Firstly Append paypal account to querystring
    $querystring .= "?business=".urlencode($site_email)."&";

    // Append amount& currency (£) to quersytring so it cannot be edited in html

    //The item name and amount can be brought in dynamically by querying the $_POST['item_number'] variable.
    $querystring .= "item_name=".urlencode($coToken)."&";
    $querystring .= "amount=".urlencode($coTotal)."&";
    $querystring .= "lc=".urlencode('US')."&";
    $querystring .= "currency_code=".urlencode('USD')."&";

    // Append paypal return addresses
    $querystring .= "return=".urlencode(stripslashes($return_url))."&";
    $querystring .= "cancel_return=".urlencode(stripslashes($cancel_url))."&";
    $querystring .= "notify_url=".urlencode($notify_url);
    //echo urldecode($querystring);
    header('location:https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'.$querystring);
    exit();
}
```

I decoded my querystring to make sure the data was correct and it seems Like it might be corrupt right after lc=US.

> ?business=site@email.com&item_name=9814992281458743510&amount=785&lc=US¤cy_code=USD&return=https : //site.com/?action=invoice&successful&cancel_return=https : //site.com/?action=invoice&cancelled¬ify_url=https : //site.com/?action=payola

(The spaces are intentional to keep the site happy with <= 1 link)

Might this be the reason PayPal is sending me to the sandbox frontpage and not processing the purchase or should I be looking elsewhere in the code? If this is the issue, what am I doing wrong?

Please forgive any transgressions in my making a post.  I've learned hundreds of things by landing here when searching, but I'm very new to actually using this site.  Please just let me know what I've done wrong.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I got the same issue, did you manage to fix it?

Comment: Hi there Beleal,  I'm sorry to say that although I did manage to fix it, it's been so long that I can no longer remember what was causing the issue and since there was no help to be had on SE, the fix was never documented.

Comment: Hello, unfortunately I didn't manage to fix it yet, this is something I will look at later on today, but I hope someone might faced this issue and have a fix.